# Making Searchable to table data in PDF using OCRMYPDF module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract, ocrmypdf

**1. Create Python OCR function**
import ocrmypdf

```
def ocr(file_path, save_path):
   ocrmypdf.ocr(file_path, save_path)
```

**2. Call and use the function.**

```
ocr("input.pdf","output.pdf")
```

Using OCRMYPDF module I am not able to make table to searchable.
How can I do that?